Собрать/пересобрать c# проект под Linux с помощью VSCode
знатоки! Есть проект c# Avalonia, собранный на Windows в VS2022, теперь надо чтобы этот проект работал под Linux (Debian). в VS нет возможности скомпилировать проект под другую ОС. Подскажите, как с помощью VSCode пересобрать проект под Linux. Никакого опыта работы с линукс нет совсем.

Ну у дотнета же есть командная строка. Может из неё прямо. Почитайте, какие там ключи, конфиги.

@CrazyElf Эмм вы что-то путаете, то что собрано под .net должно работать под любой платформой, которая поддерживается.

@evo Да, наверное вы правы. Я ещё от старых версий не отвык, где таргет платформу надо было вроде выбирать. Или вообще это ложная память )
